# ZipCode Validation Format nnnnn-nnnn

Tags: javascript, html, json

ZipCode Validation Format nnnnn-nnnn. When "-" entered by the user, it has been counted as a digit and it would take out from the max digits i made which is 9 and since the user enters"-" it will allow only 8. How I can skip "-" not to be digit and put in the right enter code here

```
function formatZipCode(value) {
    value = value.replace(/[^\/\d]/g,'');
    var Z = /(\d{5})(\d)/;
    if (value != undefined && value != '') {
        return value = value.replace(Z, '$1' + '-' + '$2');;
    }
    else {
        return value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Random note: manual zipcode validation is almost always a bad idea.  Diffferent locales have completely different zipcodes.  I've lived/worked in places with formats NNN-NNNN, AAA-NNN or AA(A)?-AA(A)? (A - alphanumeric).  Unless you're 100% sure of all zip formats that are possible by *all* users that will use the app, don't write the parser yourself.

Comment: I agree 100%, but it is only U.S zipcode. So it should be all the same.  but my point when i enter "-" it will shorten the digits to 8 as it would count as one digit entered. Is there anyway that when "-" entered it wouldn't count as a digit out from the 9 max?

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the following:

```
var z = /(\d{5})-?(\d{4})/
value = value.replace(z,"$1-$2")
```

the question mark after the hyphen indicates zero or one hyphens.

Comment: Yes. It works the same, but my point when i enter "-" it will shorten the digits to 8 as it would count as one digit entered. Is there anyway that when "-" entered it wouldn't count as a digit out from the 9 max?

Comment: I think this is pretty valid.  @AnmarAlShammari You want to validate if you have 9 digits, either with or without a hyphen.  If a user inputs complete garbage it is probably better to pop a warning.  Yet, using your initial replace ( `value.replace(/[^\/\d]/g,'');` ) you can then also do `/(\d{5})(\d{4})/` or even `/^(\d{5})(\d{4})$/` to be very pedantic.  Either that or we are just clueless in understanding what do you want to say by the "8 and 9 digits" (I admit that I do not really know what you want to say by that part).

Comment: OK. So I 'm having a zipcode text box. I'm required to maximize the entry by 10 digits. When the user inputs 1234567890 I need it be 12345-6789.
My problem also, in case the user inputs "-" such as 12-3456789, I need it to be 12345-6789. Now my input lucked with 9 digits only. no matter how much i change the maxlength in the html it doesn't allow more than 9. When the user enters 12-345678, "-" is being counted as an entry. so technecally i have only 8 numbers not 9!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a HTML form the user inputs into, then you can use it to validate zip codes by using:

> - `<input type='number'>` - Eliminates letters and symbols
> - `min` and `max` attributes  - Enforces a range
> - `<input type='submit'>` - Allows built in validation of `<form>`

Added additional function to validate digits

> First input must be 10000 to 99999
>
> AND
>
> Second input must be 1000 to 9999

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* Ensures input is 5 and 4 digits by
|| disabling submit button when 
|| requirements are not met.
*/
function digits(num1, num2) {
  var n1 = num1.length;
  var n2 = num2.length;
  if (n1 === 5 && n2 === 4) {
    zip['submit'].disabled = false;
  } else {
    zip['submit'].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  font: inherit
}

#z4 {
  width: 6ch;
}

#z5 {
  width: 7ch;
}

fieldset {
  width: 13em;
}

legend,
[type=submit] {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<!--
Ensures input is within 10000 - 99999 and
1000 - 9999 by invalidating onsubmit
-->
<form id='zip' name='zip' action='http://httpbin.org/post' method='post' onchange='digits(z5.value, z4.value)'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Zipcode</legend>
    <input id='z5' name='z5' type='number' size='5' value='00000' min='10000' max='99999'>-<input id='z4' name='z4' type='number' size='4' value='0000' min='1000' max='9999'>
    <input type='submit' id='submit' disabled>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```